# Regular Language to Regular Expression

Tags: regular-languages, regular-expressions

Let's assume I have the following regular language:

L = {1,0}*{010}{1,0}*

I would like to convert this to regex for a program. Would the equivalent regular expression for this be:

((0+1)*(010)(0+1)*)
or
((0+1)*(010)(0+1)*)*

Or is it something else completely?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the language is $\{0,1\}^* . \{010\} . \{0,1\}^*$ (where $.$ is concatenation of languages). Then the first regular expression, i.e., $(0+1)^*(010)(0+1)^*$, is correct.

The second one describes different language. The iteration of the expression (i.e., the outer parentheses) would match the empty string, while language $L$ requires at least $010$.